# Unable to connect to port 993 for IMAP on Ubuntu server with Postfix/Dovecot/MySQL

Tags: postfix, dovecot, ubuntu-16.04, sasl, sieve

Ubuntu 16.04.5
Apache2
MySQL 
Postfix w/MySQL
Dovecot
SASL2
UFW

I am trying to install a working mail server and client on this machine. I followed [this tutorial](https://linoxide.com/mail/install-configure-postfix-ubuntu/) which allows authentication through MySQL. I have all DB entries set correctly, I have set up the domain/mailbox in PostfixAdmin. All was going well until the Test login in RoundCube install. The user is unable to connect through port 993 to log in.

```
Connecting to localhost...
IMAP connect:  NOT OK(Login failed for noreply@example.com from /ip address/. Could not connect to localhost:993: Connection refused)
```

I have tried Telneting remotely to {IP address} 993 with `Connection refused` as well.

The server is running on a static IP address. RoundCube is located in the `../html/webmail/` directory and is working fine, but things like PHPMyAdmin are located at `http://{ipaddress}/phpmyadmin` since there are multiple virtual hosts for web services.

UFW has all necessary IMAP/POP3 ports allowed.

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Apache Full                ALLOW       Anywhere                  
20/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
21/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
990/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
40000:50000/tcp            ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere                  
8080                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Postfix                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
993                        ALLOW       Anywhere                  
143                        ALLOW       Anywhere                  
110                        ALLOW       Anywhere                  
995                        ALLOW       Anywhere                  
25                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
25/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Apache Full (v6)           ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
20/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
21/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
990/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
40000:50000/tcp (v6)       ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
8080 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
Postfix (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
993 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
143 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
110 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
995 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
25 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
25/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Dovecot is running

```
# 2.2.22 (fe789d2): /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# Pigeonhole version 0.4.13 (7b14904)
# OS: Linux 4.4.0-141-generic x86_64 Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS ext4
auth_debug = yes
auth_debug_passwords = yes
auth_mechanisms = plain login
auth_verbose = yes
auth_verbose_passwords = plain
mail_debug = yes
mail_location = maildir:/var/mail/vmail/%d/%n/Maildir
mail_privileged_group = mail
managesieve_notify_capability = mailto
managesieve_sieve_capability = fileinto reject envelope encoded-character vacation subaddress comparator-i;ascii-numeric relational regex imap4flags copy include variables body enotify environment mailbox date index ihave duplicate mime foreverypart extracttext
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location = 
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix = 
}
passdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
  driver = sql
}
plugin {
  sieve = file:~/sieve;active=~/.dovecot.sieve
}
protocols = " imap sieve"
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0600
    user = postfix
  }
  unix_listener auth-userdb {
    mode = 0600
    user = vmail
  }
  user = dovecot
}
ssl = no
userdb {
  args = uid=vmail gid=vmail home=/var/mail/vmail/%d/%n
  driver = static
}
verbose_ssl = yes
protocol lda {
  mail_plugins = " sieve"
}
```

Postfix config

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = $myhostname, example.com, {rootusername}, localhost.localdomain, localhost, example2.com, example3.com
myhostname = {rootusername}
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_tls_auth_only = no
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_domains_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
```

The cert/key files are not needed, I tried adding them to see if there'd be any difference. The SSL certs are for the domain and certain subdomains, there is no mail.example.com.

What seems weird is that nothing is listening on port 993, Dovecot is listening on 4190?

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      111        14759       1084/mysqld     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:587             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          34677       6207/master     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:143             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          43563       7001/dovecot    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:465             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          34683       6207/master     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          16213       1149/sshd       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          34671       6207/master     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4190            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          43523       7001/dovecot    
tcp        0    212 xx.xxx.xx.xxx:22        xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:53808    ESTABLISHED 0          75664       12943/sshd: ******** 
tcp6       0      0 :::587                  :::*                    LISTEN      0          34678       6207/master     
tcp6       0      0 :::143                  :::*                    LISTEN      0          43564       7001/dovecot    
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          18106       1614/apache2    
tcp6       0      0 :::465                  :::*                    LISTEN      0          34684       6207/master     
tcp6       0      0 :::21                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          12274       1012/vsftpd     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          16215       1149/sshd       
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          34672       6207/master     
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      0          18110       1614/apache2    
tcp6       0      0 :::4190                 :::*                    LISTEN      0          43524       7001/dovecot    
tcp6       0      0 xx.xxx.xx.xxx:80        xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:53832    TIME_WAIT   0          0           -
```

Why would Dovecot listen on 4190? I have made sure all configurations are correct, restarting all needed services, even tried rebooting the system. Is there an obvious mistake I'm making?

Answer (score 0):

So after some debugging I found that:

**Mistake 1**: Assuming `993` was the correct port. Dovecot is running on `143`. The correct setting for server in Roundcube is `tls://localhost`.

**Mistake 2**: In `/etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext` `connect` and `password_query` **must** be on seperate lines. Possibly due to copy/pasting from tutorials.

Right:

```
connect = host=localhost dbname=postfix user=postfix password=dontusep@ssw0rd

password_query = SELECT username,domain,password FROM mailbox WHERE username='%u';
```

Wrong

```
connect = host=localhost dbname=postfix user=postfix password=dontusep@ssw0rd password_query = SELECT username,domain,password FROM mailbox WHERE username='%u';
```

**Recommendation**

```
nano /etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-logging.conf
```

Set `log_path = /var/log/dovecot.log` to differentiate errors from sys errors. Dovecot will log what you've messed up.

Hope this helps someone in the future.